# Secret Santa pair allocator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a Secret-Santa gift swap with my family and we always forget who we had last year and never find time to do it so I wanted to create a simple web app to manage the whole thing. What I'm looking for is a critique on my code. Could it use more built-in JavaScript functions? How's my style?

```js
//get people from database
var people = [{name: 'TestName', spouse: 'TestNameSpouse', current: '', past: ['Dad']},
  { name: 'TestNameSpouse', spouse: 'TestName', current: '', past: ['Mom']},
  { name: 'Mom', spouse: 'Dad', current: '', past: ['TestName']}, 
  {name: 'Dad',spouse: 'Mom',current: '',past: ['SisterInLaw']},
  {name: 'Brother',spouse: 'SisterInLaw',current: '',past: ['TestNameSpouse']},
  {name: 'SisterInLaw',spouse: 'Brother',current: '',past: ['Dad']}
];

const setCurrentToBlank = (people) => people.forEach((person) => person.current = '');
const verifyGiftPartners = (people) => people.every((person) => person.current);

//Knuth shuffle
var shuffle = function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue,
    randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
};
var assignGiftPartners = function(people) {
  var peopleLeftToAssign = people.map(person => person.name);

  people.forEach(function(person) {
    var choices = peopleLeftToAssign.filter(function(personToAssign) {
      return (
        personToAssign != person.name &&
        personToAssign != person.spouse &&
        person.past.indexOf(personToAssign) === -1
      );
    });
    shuffle(choices);
    person.current = choices[0];
    var index = peopleLeftToAssign.indexOf(choices[0]);
    peopleLeftToAssign.splice(index, 1);
  });
};

var allAssigned = false;
var loopCount = 0;
while (!allAssigned) {
  assignGiftPartners(people);
  allAssigned = verifyGiftPartners(people);
  //exit loop if going too long
  if (loopCount > 50) {
    throw 'Something went wrong with the assignment';
  }
  if (!allAssigned) {
    setCurrentToBlank(people);
  }
}

//save choices into database
console.log(people);
```

Also, I realize that in a year or so we'd have to repeat people, so would it be good to limit the past size to family size - 1?

Comment: This is some nice looking code! My only personal objection would be to the anonymous function definition inside another function-- that's a little ugly.

Comment: thanks @BarryCarter! I noticed that after I posted it. I'll update it.

Comment: While I am flattered you accepted my answer, I would encourage you to see if anyone else has any responses... then see which is the *best* answer for you. Though if you feel it is useful, then you can [vote it up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'll keep a look out for other answers.

Comment: Not a review comment, but thanks for the code, it solved my problem of assigning sercet santas this year (who wants to use a website when you can run som javascript code?).

Comment: @AndreasPaulsson no problem! I've used it for my family for the last couple years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How's my style?

The style looks fine, though as [Barry Carter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/1149/barry-carter) mentioned in a comment, the definition of functions inside functions (in the [first version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/177699/1)) isn't very elegant. Perhaps the `shuffle()` function should be moved outside the `assignGiftPartners` function.

The usage of functional techniques (e.g. `.foreach()`, `.map()`) is good. If you really wanted to, you could potentially implement the logic in the `while` statement with a `foreach`.

One thought I had about the data storage is that each object could have an *id* property and the functions could utilize those *id* values, which might allow for integer comparison instead of string comparison.

> Could it use more built-in JavaScript functions?

Yes. Because you added the [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) tag, I did a quick search for "*js knuth shuffle ES-6* " and found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12646864/1575353) which uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables) to perform the swap. If you read through the comments on that answer, you will notice some discussion of the bias introduced by the change. To read more about this, see the article cited in one of those comments: [*The Danger of Naïveté*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/).

```
const shuffleArray = (array) => {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
};
```

That could replace that `shuffle` function you added. Notice it uses the [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) keyword instead of [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), since we *likely* won't need that function to output anything differently within the runtime of our program.

And it appears that function is called even when there is only one element in the array. While it likely won't save much computation time to have a *for* statement loop over an array element with one element, it would be beneficial to avoid the function call in that case. Check that the array `choice` has more than 1 element:

```
if (choices.length > 1) {
    shuffleArray(choices);
}
```

You could also simplify the functions `verifyGiftPartners()` and `setCurrentToBlank` using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (like you did for `var peopleLeftToAssign`).

```
const verifyGiftPartners = (people) => people.filter((person) => !person.current).length <= 0;

const setCurrentToBlank = (people) => people.forEach((person) => person.current = '');
```

Additionally, instead of checking gift partners with [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and comparing the length, you could possibly use [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
const verifyGiftPartners = (people) => people.every((person) => person.current);
```

Comment: Thanks @SamOnela! Good ideas  for improvements using ecmascript-6. I'm not sure what you mean by using ids instead of names. Are you saying that the built in functions might use an id?

Comment: That is an absolutely TERRIBLE shuffle function, and it is extremely biased. Never use something like that.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/5ssfzj69/1/). The distribution (look at the console) is far from even. You can compare that the unbiased shuffle I made.

Comment: Thanks Kruga - I will update my answer to not recommend that. Do you want to comment on [that gist](https://gist.github.com/guilhermepontes/17ae0cc71fa2b13ea8c20c94c5c35dc4)?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a review of the coding style and syntax, but of the algorithm used.

### Permutations and randomised rule based selection.

A random search for a set of permutations is never a good method, especially if the set of previous results reduce the size of the set of valid permutations for the next set.

#### Random solution guessing

Your problem is finding one of a set of solutions. There are only a finite set of possible solutions.

Your code uses a random guess method.

Each iteration you randomly guess a possible combination then test its validity. Because the set of valid solutions gets smaller each year, your code needs to make more guesses as the number of valid solutions gets smaller but the set you are guessing in remains the same size.

This method also has been limited (to 50) and thus you could always have a chance of not finding a solution. For the first year there is a relatively small chance of not finding a solution, but this grows quickly. In three years you will need to (on average) run the code 5 times to find a solution.

Also the limit you must surely have seen is that after 4 years there are no more possible solutions, as everyone has given to everyone. This should be obvious from the code as well, but it still tries to guess a solution where there is none.

There is no need for the code to throw an error. The solutions are known and fixed, so there is no need to guess.

#### Systematic solution computation.

To do this effectively you need to know the set of all valid solutions. Once you have that set you just randomly select one. There is no need to search for valid solutions as you are only selecting from known valid values.

Pre-computation of the set of valid solutions has a limit, as the possible number of solutions quickly grows with the complexity of a solution. For 6 people there are 80 solutions that are valid, for 10 people that is approaching a million. For 20 people you need to start applying some serious optimisation and storage compression to use this method.

#### Abstraction

If you compute them systematically and hold them as an abstracted data set, e.g. each person is a letter `A,B,C,D,E,F` that identifies them both as an entry in the data struc and a position in the abstracted data, e.g. `"A"` is 1st person in a solution string and the first person in the `people` array. A solution for a particular year is a string e.g. `"CDEFAB"` which means person `A` gives to `C`, person `B` gives to `D`, `C` to `E` and so on.

If you ignore the previous year the possible solutions are only 80.

#### Computing permutations.

For your data the following is all valid solutions.

```
var allValidSolutions = "DCFEBA,DCFEAB,DCEFBA,DCEFAB,ECFADB,ECFABD,ECFBDA,ECFBAD,ECAFDB,ECAFBD,ECBFDA,ECBFAD,FCEADB,FCEABD,FCEBDA,FCEBAD,FCAEDB,FCAEBD,FCBEDA,FCBEAD,CDFEBA,CDFEAB,CDEFBA,CDEFAB,EDFACB,EDFABC,EDFBCA,EDFBAC,EDAFCB,EDAFBC,EDBFCA,EDBFAC,FDEACB,FDEABC,FDEBCA,FDEBAC,FDAECB,FDAEBC,FDBECA,FDBEAC,CEFADB,CEFABD,CEFBDA,CEFBAD,CEAFDB,CEAFBD,CEBFDA,CEBFAD,DEFACB,DEFABC,DEFBCA,DEFBAC,DEAFCB,DEAFBC,DEBFCA,DEBFAC,FEBADC,FEBACD,FEABDC,FEABCD,CFEADB,CFEABD,CFEBDA,CFEBAD,CFAEDB,CFAEBD,CFBEDA,CFBEAD,DFEACB,DFEABC,DFEBCA,DFEBAC,DFAECB,DFAEBC,DFBECA,DFBEAC,EFBADC,EFBACD,EFABDC,EFABCD".split(",");
```

This was created with the following code. ***Note*** this is a brute force method. You should do some research into optimal methods if you need to include more than a dozen people.

```
function permutations2Of(chars) {
    var i,j;
    const count = chars.length;
    const sets = [];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
        for (j = 0; j < count; j ++) {
            if (j !== i) { sets.push(chars[j] + chars[i]) }
        }
    }
    return sets;
}
function isSetValid(set, ofSet) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < ofSet.length) {
        if (set.indexOf(ofSet[i ++]) === -1) { return false }
    }
    return true;
}
function findUnique(arr, ofSet, result = [], index = 0, current = "") {
    var i;
    const testSet = index === arr.length - 1; 
    for (i = 0;  i < arr[index].length; i ++)  {
        const aSet = current + arr[index][i];
        if (testSet) {
            if (isSetValid(aSet, ofSet)) { result.push(aSet) }
        } else {
            result = findUnique(arr, ofSet, result, index + 1, aSet);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
const AB = permutations2Of("CDEF");
const CD = permutations2Of("ABEF");
const EF = permutations2Of("ABCD");
const combos = findUnique([AB, CD, EF], "ABCDEF");
```

This is based on the smallest unit being a couple (e.g. `AB` is the first and second person, and they can give only to persons `"CDEF"`)

It calculates all the possible permutations for each couple and then calculates all the possible permutations for all couples.

The  function `findUnique` uses recursion to create all possible solutions and then calls the function `isValidSet` to test if the solution should be kept.

The set of solutions should only be calculated once; once computed it can be retrieved from a data store and filtered when there is a need for extra rules to be applied - e.g. last years results.

#### Random solution without the guesswork.

Now it is very easy to find the first years arrangement.

```
var secretSantas = combos[Math.random() * combos.length | 0];
```

And convert to your data:

```
const baseCode = "A".charCodeAt(0);
secretSantas.split("").forEach((id, index) => {
    const personIndex = id.charCodeAt(0) - baseCode;
    people[index].current = people[personIndex];
});
```

#### Additional rules.

The above does not consider the previous year's gifts, but that can be stored as the abstracted string e.g. `"DEFGAB"`. As there are only 4 people for each person to give to there are only 4 years before you are forced to repeat. If you limit the repeat only to 4 years then after the 3<sup>rd</sup> year everyone will know who is giving to who (if anybody bothered to keep track that is).

So the better rule is to just not repeat two years. You can't give to the person you gave to last year.

Then you can use a filter on the `combos` array to eliminate any invalid combination due to previous years results.

```
const lastYearsCombo = "CDEFAB".split("");
const comboFiltered = combos.filter(combo => {
     for (var i = 0; i < lastYearsCombo.length; i++) {
         if (combo[i] === lastYearsCombo[i]) { return false }
     }
     return true;
});
```

`comboFiltered` will only have 17 possible combinations as the rest have been eliminated due to the previous year. The random selection is still the same.

```
var secretSantas = comboFiltered[Math.random() * comboFiltered.length | 0];
```

Answer (score 3):

[Shuffling an array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is very different from sorting it randomly. For the shuffling to be fair, you need a random number generator and you must ask it for exactly \$\log_2(n!)\$ bits of randomness, or a multiple thereof. Otherwise it cannot be fair. \$n\$ is the number of elements in the array.

Furthermore, a *comparison function* must be stable. That means, when I call the function multiple times with the same arguments, it must always return the same value. Your random function doesn't do this. Depending on the sorting algorithm, this can lead to endless loops, exceptions, or generally *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Good point on _shuffling_ vs _sorting_! I do understand the importance of comparison function stability. Is there an "easy way" to comprehend the bits of randomness requirement(s)?

Comment: Roland - can you address anything else, e.g. what the OP asked for (i.e. "_Could it use more built-in JavaScript functions? How's my style? etc._")?